# Расположение таблицы grid на всю область фрэйма вкладки tab

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, позиционирование

Не понимаю, почему при позиционировании виджетов с помощью Grid фрейм вкладок не покрывает всю область приложения. Нужно по высоте увеличить таблицу до нижней границы так, чтобы фрэйм покрывал всю область программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import mysql.connector  
import config  
from tkinter import ttk  
import tkinter as tk  

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=config.host,
    user=config.user,
    password=config.password,
    database=config.database
)

mycursor = db.cursor()

mycursor.execute("DESCRIBE books")
for x in mycursor:
    print(x)

class LibraryDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()  
        self.root.geometry("1020x586")  
        self.root.title("Library")  
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.iconbitmap("library.ico") 
        self.user_emoji = [":arrows_counterclockwise:"]

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="alt", settings={
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {
                    "tabmargins": [2, 4, 2, 0],
                    "background": "peachpuff2"
                }
            },
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {
                    "padding": [14, 6],
                    "font": ('Open Sans', '9', 'bold'),
                    "background": "lavender",
                    "foreground": "black"
                },
                "map": {
                    "background": [("selected", "antiquewhite")]
                },
                "label": {"background": "white"}
            },
            "TFrame": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": "antiquewhite"
                }
            }
        })
        s.theme_use("MyStyle")

        
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)

        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.main_frame)

        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab4 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab5 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab6 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab7 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab8 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)

        self.tab_control.add(self.tab1, text='Книги')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab2, text='Автор книги')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab3, text='Авторы')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab4, text='Жанры книги')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab5, text='Жанры')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab6, text='Издания')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab7, text='Читатели')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab8, text='Выдача книг')

        self.tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")

        self.tab1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

   
        self.tab1_obj = FirstTab(self.tab1)
        self.tab2_obj = SecondTab(self.tab2)



class FirstTab:
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        self.parent = parent  

    def frstframetab1(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        # создаем лэйбл
        per_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Список книг", bg="antiquewhite",font=("Montserrat", 14))
        per_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W" )
        add_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Добавить", bg="thistle", width=9, font=("Montserrat", 10, "bold"))
        add_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=130, pady=0, sticky="W")
        del_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Удалить", bg="thistle", width=9, font=("Montserrat", 10, "bold"))
        del_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=160, pady=0, sticky="W")
        isbn_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="ISBN",bg="antiquewhite", font=("Montserrat", 12))
        isbn_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W" )
        isbn_entry = tk.Entry(self.parent, bg="aliceblue", width=13).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=60, pady=10, sticky="W")
        name_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Название", bg="antiquewhite", font=("Montserrat", 12))
        name_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=153, pady=10, sticky="W")
        name_entry = tk.Entry(self.parent, bg="aliceblue", width=18).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=210, pady=10, sticky="W")
        author_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Автор", bg="antiquewhite", font=("Montserrat", 12))
        author_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=333, pady=10, sticky="W")
        author_entry = tk.Entry(self.parent, bg="aliceblue", width=15).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=390, pady=10, sticky="W")
        search_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Найти", bg="lightcyan", width=8, font=("Montserrat", 10))
        search_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=510, pady=10, sticky="W")
        inv_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Инвентарь", width=9, bg="powderblue", font=("Montserrat", 11))
        inv_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=664, pady=10, sticky="W")
        filauthor_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Фильтр по автору", width=25, bg="darksalmon", font=("Montserrat", 10))
        filauthor_button.grid(row=2, rowspan=2, column=0, padx=780, pady=10, sticky="se")
        filname_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Фильтр по названию", bg="darksalmon", width=25, font=("Montserrat", 10))
        filname_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=780, pady=50, sticky="se")
        filisbn_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Фильтр по ISBN", width=25, bg="darksalmon", font=("Montserrat", 10))
        filisbn_button.grid(row=3, rowspan=2, column=0, padx=780, pady=90, sticky="se")
        back_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="<", bg="palegreen", width=4, font=("Arial", 8))
        back_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=780, pady=73, sticky="nw")
        next_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text=">", bg="palegreen", width=4, font=("Arial", 8))
        next_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=820, pady=73, sticky="nw")
        change_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Изменить", width=10, bg="plum2", font=("Montserrat", 10))
        change_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=780, pady=0, sticky="nw")
        save_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Сохранить", width=11, bg="palegreen1", font=("Montserrat", 10))
        save_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=780, pady=0, sticky="en")
        rollback_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Откат изменений", width=25, bg="skyblue", font=("Montserrat", 10))
        rollback_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=780, pady=35, sticky="n")

    def select_all_books(self):
        # Выполняем запрос к базе данных для получения всех книг
        # mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
        # rows = mycursor.fetchall()  # Получаем все строки результата запроса

        # Создаем таблицу для отображения информации о книгах
        table = ttk.Treeview(self.parent, columns=(
        'ISBN', 'Название', 'Издание', 'Город', 'Год', 'Кол-во страниц', 'Кол-во экземпляров'), show='headings')
        table.column('ISBN', width=40, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.column('Название', width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.column('Издание', width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.column('Город', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.column('Год', width=80, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.column('Кол-во страниц', width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.column('Кол-во экземпляров', width=170, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        table.heading('ISBN', text='ISBN')
        table.heading('Название', text='Название')
        table.heading('Издание', text='Издание')
        table.heading('Город', text='Город')
        table.heading('Год', text='Год')
        table.heading('Кол-во страниц', text='Кол-во страниц')
        table.heading('Кол-во экземпляров', text='Кол-во экземпляров')

        # # Заполняем таблицу данными из базы данных
        # for row in row:
        #     table.insert('', tk.END, values=row)

        # Помещаем таблицу на фрейм
        table.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=0, sticky="W")



class SecondTab:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def frstframetab2(self):
        # создаем лэйбл
        per_label = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Список книг")
        per_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    library_db = LibraryDB()
    library_db.tab1_obj.frstframetab1()
    library_db.tab1_obj.select_all_books()
    library_db.tab2_obj.frstframetab2()
    library_db.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При размещении через `grid` чтобы фрейм расширялся в окне, нужно для самого окна задать, чтобы его нулевой столбец и нулевая строка сетки имели вес 1. Чтобы `Notebook` расширялся в этом фрейме, нужно те же настройки выполнить для самого фрейма.

В `tab1` наоборот это нужно убрать, иначе его "нулевая" ячейка попытается занять максимальное пространство. В `tab1` имеет смысл добавить вес, например, строке с таблицей, чтобы таблица расширилась по высоте (в коде ниже я это не делал).

Т.е. настраивать нужно сетку (веса колонок и строк) у фрейма или окна, где виджет размещается, а не сетку виджета.

Итого, фрагмент кода с изменениями:

```
self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # <<<
self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # <<<

self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.main_frame)
self.tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")
self.main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # <<<
self.main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # <<<

self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab4 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab5 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab6 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab7 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
self.tab8 = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)

self.tab_control.add(self.tab1, text='Книги')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab2, text='Автор книги')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab3, text='Авторы')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab4, text='Жанры книги')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab5, text='Жанры')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab6, text='Издания')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab7, text='Читатели')
self.tab_control.add(self.tab8, text='Выдача книг')

# self.tab1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # ---
# self.tab1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # ---
   
self.tab1_obj = FirstTab(self.tab1)
self.tab2_obj = SecondTab(self.tab2)
```

В принципе, для размещения одного виджета с авторасширением удобнее использовать `pack` вместо `grid`, там достаточно все настройки в самом `pack` указать:

```
self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
self.main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.main_frame)
self.tab_control.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

[image: Скриншот]